# windows 8 combobox hides behind WebView

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I have a grid view which has multiple items.

Each Item is a Webview. Now My issue is that I have a ComboBox above the GridView. When I select Combobox the drop down hides behind the GridView item (i.e Webview). Now I cannot use a WebViewBrush since I have multiple WebView items inside the grid view. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

XAML UI is always behind a WebView window - this is a typical airspace issue. You have to use WebViewBrush for any WebViews that might obscure your XAML controls. Some alternatives include modifying your UI layout - e.g. going to a separate page to display your selector control or moving ui elements about so they don't collide or implementing all of it in HTML.

Comment: Any idea how to use a WebViewBrush for an entire GridView which occupies 80% of the screen ??

Comment: Well, you probably need one for each WebView. That's how it works iirc.

Comment: My each Webview is an item within a GridView. So in the data template im using I can have that rectangle used for a WebViewBrush. But then after that where I can write the part of code to make WebViewBrush work for every webView???

Comment: It depends on how you populate your GridView. You could use a UserControl for each item that has a WebView, WebViewBrush and a dependency property bound to a view model property that you update when your ComboBox drop down opens or closes causing the switch between WebView or WebViewBrush. You could also use something like Prism EventAggregator or MVVM Light's Messenger to request all WebViews to switch when a ComboBox opens, etc.